# How to reset DisplayName to empty using Sitecore PowerShell Extensions?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I wanted to know better way to reset Display Name to empty using PowerShell scripts.

I have written below script..

```powershell
$item = Get-Item "/sitecore/content/home"
$item.Editing.BeginEdit()
$item["{B5E02AD9-D56F-4C41-A065-A133DB87BDEB}"] = ""
$item.Editing.EndEdit()
```

which works but I'm not sure its the correct way or not.

I also tried something like `$item[Sitecore::FieldIDs::DisplayName] = ""` which doesn't work ..

Please help.

Comment: I'm using `Sitecore 7.5` and `Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 4.0.0.0`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use this to set it to empty. With this you don't need to wrap the change with `BeginEdit` and `EndEdit`

```powershell
$item."__Display Name" = ""
```

You only need the quotes here as there is a space in the name, a field without a space can be accessed like so: `$item.MyField`

If you actually want to reset the field value, rather than explicitly set it as empty, use:

```powershell
Reset-ItemField -Item $item -IncludeStandardFields -Name "__Display Name"
```

Comment: I'm getting this error `The term 'Reset-ItemField' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet` I'm using `Sitecore 7.5` and `Sitecore PowerShell Extensions 4.0.0.0`

Comment: Hmm I think this command was in 4.0, I'm just checking that for you.

Comment: Yes this was in SPE 4.0. How did you confirm the SPE version? Did you use the About icon in the ribbon of ISE?

Comment: I have checked from file properties of `Cognifide.PowerShell.dll` assembly

Comment: @Harsh and I resolved the issue above which was unrelated to the question in hand, he had a corrupt installation of 4.0 and reinstalling it gave access to the command.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```powershell
Reset-ItemField -Item $item -Name "__Display Name" -IncludeStandardFields
```

source: [Reset-ItemField docs](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Reset-ItemField.html)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```powershell
Get-Item "master:/sitecore/content/home" | Reset-ItemField -IncludeStandardFields -Name "__Display Name"
```

See reference [here](https://sitecorepowershell.gitbooks.io/sitecore-powershell-extensions/content/appendix/commands/Reset-ItemField.html). The `IncludeStandardFields` is needed as this field is a Sitecore standard field.